# Clicking in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal creates gibberish?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

Opening the terminal and getting gibberish + can't abort operation with ctrl+c.

I didn't add anything to bashrc. I am clicking in the terminal black zone and get `G#_` symbols. For the `^C` if I want to stop / terminate the openvpn tab, it doesn't work. The only way to stop it is to kill the process.

Used the `/usr/bin/reset` so far.

Please advise.

Comment: It maybe someone (or you) have added commands to your ~/.bashrc that are causing it; or you've set an invalid or strange $PS1 etc.   It's unclear as you've provided few clues as to what you mean (gibberish? and how does the ^C relate??)

Comment: @guiverc I didn't add anything to bashrc. I mean when I click the terminal I am getting G#_ symbols.
For the ^C if I want to stop / terminate the openvpn tab, it doesn't work. 
The only way to stop it is to kill the process.

Comment: There was no mention of "openvpn" in your question. Please provide any additional information that maybe helpful by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1176550/edit) your question.

Comment: @DKBose sure I will update it now